# Spacing after displayed maths, before an \item

Tags: math-mode, lists, line-spacing

This question concerns spacing after displayed maths, and how it interacts with spacing inside an `enumerate` environment. Specifically, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
First line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\[a+b=c\] % The spacing above and below is the same
Second line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\begin{enumerate}
\item First line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\[a+b=c.\] % The spacing below is bigger than the spacing above
\item Second item. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\item Third item. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

At a basic level, in this MWE I want the vertical spacing before/after displayed maths to be the same in both of these instances.

More generally (and technically), I want `\itemsep` (or whatever is adding the extra space) to interact with `\belowdisplayskip` as if they were `\addvspace`-type spaces, so the maximum of the two is taken. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

*Note:* I've included `amsmath` above, but this issue also happens without `amsmath` loaded. In the place where I need this, I actually also need it to work with the `enumitem` package, but I don't think this will interfere with any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's how it's supposed to be, according to how lists are implemented. Any `\item` starts a paragraph and TeX inserts `\parskip` glue, that lists set equal to the value of `\parsep` (that's set by the class), besides `\itemsep`; this `\itemsep` doesn't get through, in this case, but `\parskip` does.

Example (two column format for easier comparison)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
First line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\[a+b=c\] % The spacing above and below is the same
Second line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\newpage
\begin{enumerate}
\item First line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\[a+b=c.\] % The spacing below is bigger than the spacing above
\item Second item. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\item Third item. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Fixed:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
First line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\[a+b=c\] % The spacing above and below is the same
Second line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\newpage
\begin{enumerate}
\item First line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\[a+b=c.\vspace{-\parskip}\] % The spacing below is equal to the spacing above
\item Second item. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\item Third item. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It may make sense to load the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
\begin{document}
First line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\[a+b=c\] % The spacing above and below is the same
Second line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\newpage
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\glueexpr\itemsep+\parsep\relax,parsep=0pt]
\item First line. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\[a+b=c.\] % The spacing below is equal to the spacing above
\item Second item. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\item Third item. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

but this will of course impact on paragraphs inside a single item.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Here's a follow-up problem: the first solution doesn't work when you use the `fleqn` option with amsmath. In this case, `\vspace` seems to have no effect within a displayed maths environment. Any ideas?

Comment: @RobertBrignall The `fleqn` option is always of a hindrance. :(

Comment: @RobertBrignall With `fleqn` the equation is boxed and the `\vadjust` item created by `\vspace` doesn't migrate. With `Second\vadjust pre{\vskip-\parskip} item` you fix it. Not a pretty hack, I agree.